# COUNTIFS to find pairs in Column A and B, resulting in 0s

Tags: excel, excel-formula

COUNTIFS to find pairs in Column A and B, resulting in 0s when dragged.

I am trying to get an equation to calculate the number of times each pair of productkey/orderId appears in columns A & B together.

I believe my equation needs adjusting and I am not sure what is wrong.

=IF($D3=E$2,"-",COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5000,$D3,$B$2:$B$5000,E$2) + COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5000,E$2,$B$2:$B$5000,$D3))

I keep getting 0s and no pairs found and I do not believe this to correct.
What adjustments should I make to the equation to find the pairs? I am fine with scratching this whole equation.

[image: Equation Highlight]

[image: Dragged Results]

File bin if needed.
https://filebin.net/h3mxcz10u1w7u1eo

Comment: for testing purposes change the value of E2 to 10285 and D3 to 694 and see what the value in E3 becomes.  From what is dsiplayed in your screenshot, non of the values are in your two column hence you are getting a value of 0?  Can say for sure since your data goes off the screen.  You should be testing with a small portion say 10 rows of datat to see if it works and once working expand it out to your 5000 rows

Comment: what is in row 2, Products? and in column D, Orders? or the other way around? either way, products seem to start in 600+ and order is 10000+. And row 2 and column D start in 1... you would have to drag a lot before finding a match

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just COUNTIFS in each row, like: COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$50000;A1;$B$2:$B$50000;B1)   That way, you only count with the values that are known to be there. You can then filter by the values greater than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Function**

Enter following in cell E3:

```
=SUM(1*($A$2:$A$43&$B$2:$B$43=$D2&E$1))
```

**Links**

Google sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PCc_7o65ppEnFFmMRt5HP2gdzecMkuGnn_E3dlUQ3Fc/edit?usp=sharing) (note: sheets may not handle equation, so screenshot of Microsoft Excel below as evidence of application/implementation).

**Screenshot**

[image: Application in Microsoft Excel]